# How to keep a sentence lined up perfectly after making the browser smaller?

Tags: html, css

To be honest, I can't find the right words to adress my problem, but I'll try.
[First picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg1FY.png)
In this picture, all of the first words of each sentence are lined up perfectly.

[second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptsfh.png)
But in this picture, the first word of each sentence doesn't line up with eachother. This happens when I place it in the center with text-align. I know why it does that, but sadly I'm not able to fix that what probably is a very easy thing to fix.

This is the code that I tested this with:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            #text {
                text-align: left;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 470px;
            }

            @media all and (max-width: 1300px) {
            #text {
            text-align: center;
            }
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="text"> 
                just some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random text
                just some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random text
                just some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random text
                just some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random text
                just some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random text
                just some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random textjust some random text
        </div>
    </body>
```

Any help would be appriciated, thanks.

Comment: make a snippet of your problem

Comment: `text-align:justify`? if its not working, show us your html and css code..

Comment: I've put the code in there, sorry about that.

I've tried using justify before. It kinda worked, but it creates a couple of gaps between some words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the gaps use this

```
#text {
    text-align:justify;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Here is the sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zv2eoyu/4/)..

**Note:** `word-break: break-all` breaks any word/letter unto the next line. The words or texts will be harder to read..

Comment: @cst1992 yeah i know that but if the OP is ok of using it then why not use it?

Comment: I know, just putting it out there. Maybe you could add it as a warning in your answer or something.

Answer (score 2):

I think `text-align:justify;` is what you want to use. Please check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_text-align&preval=justify) to see more details and the different options of `text-align`.